# External filter with custom button text and multi-column

Tags: jquery, filter, tablesorter

I am using Tablesorter and would like to add a few shortcut buttons for my users to help them fill in the filter-boxes. Buttons work fine if used as described here:

- https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-custom-search.html#how_to_add_custom_filter_types

and here:

- https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-custom-search2.html

I need to change the label of the button i.e. filter on something that is different from the button label. How do I add this?

Also: How do I enable filtering in multiple columns when different buttons are pressed? Right now all other filters are erased when a button is pressed

My button jQuery code for using external buttons looks like this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
        var $t = $(this),
          col = $t.data('filter-column'), // zero-based index
          filter = [];

        filter[col] = $t.text(); // text to add to filter
        $('#sorttable').trigger('search', [ filter ]);
        return false;
      });
```

And I would add a filter using

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-filter-column="1">50 - 59</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-filter-column="0">DIV</button>
```

The "DIV" text I would like to replace with something else, while still applying a filter that actually reads "DIV" to column 0, and at the same time I would like not to erase the "50 - 59" filter that the first button might have added to column 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up the code to get one or more queries from one button ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/590/))

HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-filter-column="0,1" data-filter-query="abc,>50">Combo</button>
```

Script

```
$(function() {

  $('button').click(function() {
    var i,
      $t = $(this),
      col = $t.attr('data-filter-column').split(/\s*,\s*/), // zero-based index
      query = $t.attr('data-filter-query').split(/\s*,\s*/),
      filter = [];

    for (i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
      var n = parseInt(col[i], 10);
      filter[n] = query[i]; // text to add to filter
    }
    $('#sorttable').trigger('search', [filter]);
    return false;
  });

  $('#sorttable').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'filter']
  });
});
```

Or, you can use the built-in methods to search a range of columns - see [this demo](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-external-inputs.html).

---

Update: Try [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/591/) that updates the existing filters with each button click. Use the reset button to clear everything

```
$(function() {

  var $table = $('#sorttable');

  $('button:not(.reset)').click(function() {
    var i,
      $t = $(this),
      col = $t.data('filter-column'), // zero-based index
      query = $t.attr('data-filter-query'),
      // get the current filter values
      filter = $.tablesorter.getFilters($table);
    filter[col] = query; // text to add to filter
    $table.trigger('search', [filter]);
    return false;
  });

  $table.tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
    widgetOptions: {
      filter_reset: '.reset'
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately this would mean that I would have to make buttons for every combination of filters possible. The two buttons were an example. I have 10 predefined buttons that adds different filters to three of my columns and your suggestion would add quite a lot of combo buttons if I understand it correctly?

I didn't find the data-filter-quiry when looking through the examples, so I will start using that one. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. I'll try it out. Thank you!

Comment: Just to close things off, the second suggestion hit the nail. Very much appreciated. Love the Tablesorter script and how it has evolved btw :-)